# Cannot get NuGet packages from projects

Tags: nuget

I try to learn Unit test in VS2019 and I get error
On Clean project
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

On package manager

```
PM> dotnet restore 
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MyProjects2019\source\repos\Bank\Bank\Bank.csproj (in 348 ms).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft V
isual Studio\2019\Community\MyProjects2019\source\repos\Bank\Bank.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2019\Community\MyProjects2019\source\repos\Bank\Bank.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot [C:\Program Files (x86
)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MyProjects2019\source\repos\Bank\Bank.sln]
PM>
```

All package are like install but I get error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those on Linux systems, the error happens due to some missing environment variables.
Fix them with

```sh
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt # On Ubuntu and related distros
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/dev/null
```

NOTE : The path to certificates might vary depending on the distribution

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot". So, your computer's certificate store does not trust any of the certificates in the certificate chain. I don't know how to restore the operating system's default trusted CA list, but if you ever ran a program, or manually modified the certificate store, to remove a trusted CA, you need to undo those changes.